# How to format numbers as strings to be in the form "xxx.xxx.xxx,yy"in Java?

Tags: java, number-formatting, decimalformat

is there a class in Java that lets you format a number like "102203345.32" to this "102.203.345,32" and return a string type?

I would like to obtain a String where the thousands are separated by the '.' and the decimals are separated by a comma ','.

Could someone help me please? I found a class DecimalFormat and I tried to customize it:

```
public class CustomDecimalFormat {
static public String customFormat(String pattern, double value ) {
      DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
      String output = myFormatter.format(value);
      return output;
}
}
```

but when I call the customFormat method like this: CustomDecimalFormat.customFormat("###.###,00") I get an exception...

What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: please add the stacktrace of the exception you get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure to read and understand the **Special Pattern Characters** section of the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), especially this note:

> The characters listed here are used in non-localized patterns. Localized patterns use the corresponding characters taken from this formatter's `DecimalFormatSymbols` object instead, and these characters lose their special status.

If you have done that, it should be clear to you that you must use [the appropriate constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#DecimalFormat%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols%29) and supply the appropriately configured separator/grouping chars, whereas in the pattern itself the dot and the comma have a special meaning.

All the complexity above is there for your convenience, actually: it allows you to customize the number format *and* have it localized.

Here's a code sample which worked for me:

```
final DecimalFormatSymbols syms = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
syms.setDecimalSeparator(',');
syms.setGroupingSeparator('.');
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###.00", syms);
System.out.println(myFormatter.format(1234.12));
```

You can also use a variant where you apply the *localized pattern*, for more intuitive code:

```
final DecimalFormatSymbols syms = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
syms.setDecimalSeparator(',');
syms.setGroupingSeparator('.');
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("", syms);
myFormatter.applyLocalizedPattern("###.###,00");
System.out.println(myFormatter.format(1234.12));
```

Comment: I worked, thank you! Is there a way to round up the decimal e.g. if I have 1234.128 as a decimal, format it like "1.234,13" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `GERMAN` number format

```
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN).format(102203345.32)
```

Comment: There is no need to have this string substitution kludge if pattern is properly defined!

Answer (score 0):

First of all,
you misplaced the comma and decimal points. Your format should be : ###,###.00 instead of ###.###,00 ...

Also check with your Locale, it has an effect on the format. See the link below.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

Comment: read for comprehension maybe? Their requested format is correct for what they want to do, this isn't an answer.