# Pattern for Integers in Java (###.###.###)

Tags: java

I need to format Integers to a different pattern.

Example:

```
Input: 13040321
Output: 13.040.321
```

Example2:

```
Input: 2323
Output: 2.323
```

I tried use it:

```
    String pattern = "###.###.###";
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern); //ERROR HERE
    decimalFormat.setGroupingSize(3);
    String formattedValue = decimalFormat.format(value);
    return formattedValue;
```

I cannot have outputs using "," or decimals.

Comment: Which error? Could you be more specific?

Comment: I don't think you can have multiple decimal separators.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format numbers as strings to be in the form "xxx.xxx.xxx,yy"in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456350/how-to-format-numbers-as-strings-to-be-in-the-form-xxx-xxx-xxx-yyin-java)

Comment: a format exception.. really, it's not possible, because . is to decimal, but, my format understand "." as group of 3 numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at the [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) docs, I can say, that `.` is used for decimal separator. If you would like to group numbers, you should use `,` instead. Also you should specify locale, so the following code should work fine:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat();
decimalFormat.setGroupingSize(3);
DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
decimalFormatSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');
decimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(decimalFormatSymbols);
System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(value));
```

Comment: +1 for the first part but for the code, the OP doesn't really need the `.`, and also don't need to set the group size explicitly the pattern can help determine the group size, also probably need to call [`setGroupingSeparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html#setGroupingSeparator(char)).

Comment: It seems that OP needs `.` as grouping separator. In that case try using different locale like `Locale.GERMAN`.

Comment: Missed this requirement =) Thanks for pointing that, @BheshGurung

Comment: @HelioBentzen you are welcome. Please note I've made a small edit - you don't even need a pattern

Comment: Yes, is better and clean now, @nikis

Answer (score 2):

The DecimalFormat's pattern requires you use the comma as the grouping character. So your pattern has to be `#,###`. Since you want to *output* periods for grouping, you would need to set your own [`DecimalFormatSymbols`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html) [`setDecimalFormatSymbols`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setDecimalFormatSymbols%28java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols%29)

I assume this formatting is consistent for a particular locale. But if it isn't, your can construct your own custom instance...

Comment: For my output I cannot use ',' to separate. I need use '.' really. Maybe need make string formats.

Answer (score 1):

An extremely dirty (but working) solution:

```
  public static String pattern(int number) {
    String textValue = String.valueOf(number);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(textValue);
    String reversedTextValue = sb.reverse().toString();

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < reversedTextValue.length(); i++) {
      result.append(i % 3 == 0 ? "." + reversedTextValue.charAt(i) : reversedTextValue.charAt(i));
    }

    return result.reverse().toString().substring(0, result.length() - 1);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String getPattern(Integer i, String pattern) {
    //assumes a pattern that uses '#' to represent where a digit goes
    int y = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String iStr = Integer.toString(i);
    for (int x = 0; x < iStr.length(); i++) {
        while (y < pattern.length()) {
            if ('#' == pattern.charAt(y)) {
                sb.append(iStr.charAt(x));
                y++;
                break;
            } else {
                sb.append(pattern.charAt(y));
                y++;                    
            }
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```